# problems with processing my insert query in php

Tags: php, sql

Hello i have a problem with my query ill keep getting errors from my query

this is my error;

> Error: BEGIN; INSERT INTO `our_work` (`id`) VALUES ('6'); INSERT INTO
>   `our_work_portf_img` (`portf_id`, `img_id`) VALUES ('6', '7'); INSERT
>   INTO `our_work_images` (`img_id`, `image`) VALUES ('7', 'adawd.jpg');
>   COMMIT;  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INSERT INTO `our_work` (`id`) VALUES ('6'); INSERT INTO `our_wo'
>   at line 3

i've tried many things but i noticed one thing if i copy the $query string and i posted the query directly in mysql the problem will not accorded and it works just how i hoped it would.

Does anyone noticed the problem in my query cause im literal out of ideas.

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

if(isset($_POST['submit_new_img'])){ 

$pjt_dtls = $_POST['project_details'];
$categories = $_POST['categories'];
$link = $_POST['link'];
$image_path = "adawd.jpg";//$_POST['file']; //$_POST['image'];

$row_id ='6';//++$num_rows['i'];
$image_id ='7'; //++$num_rows['ii'];

$sql = "
    BEGIN;

    INSERT INTO `our_work` 
     (`id`)
    VALUES
     ('{$row_id}');

    INSERT INTO `our_work_portf_img`
     (`portf_id`, `img_id`) 
    VALUES
     ('{$row_id}', '{$image_id}');

    INSERT INTO `our_work_images`
     (`img_id`, `image`) 
    VALUES
     ('{$image_id}', '{$image_path}');

    COMMIT;
";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
}
```

Comment: [`mysqli->query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) -> `Performs **a** query on the database`. Your `$sql` is not **a** query.  You might want to try using [`mulit_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) -> `if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE)`

Comment: why are you using single quotes around variables like $row_id, portf_id, img_id and etc in your insert statement?  Try echoing $sql and see if the query is correct or not

Comment: @TheGuest The quotes are around the variables because the variables are strings when they go to the DB. I think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$conn->query($sql)` does not work with multi-query like yours

you need to use [multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) instead

also here is nice comment:

> Please note that there is no need for the semicolon after the last
>   query. That wasted more than hour of my time...

Comment: can i also limit the input of query's giving?

Comment: @user3638080 your query is not giving any input, what do you want to limit?